# Using continue in a switch statement

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement, break, continue

I want to jump from the middle of a `switch` statement, to the loop statement in the following code:

```
while (something = get_something())
{
    switch (something)
    {
    case A:
    case B:
        break;
    default:
        // get another something and try again
        continue;
    }
    // do something for a handled something
    do_something();
}
```

Is this a valid way to use `continue`? Are `continue` statements ignored by `switch` statements? Do C and C++ differ on their behaviour here?

Comment: Your idea is fine but the loop above will never execute `do_something()`.

Comment: Even if control reaches case A or case B?

Comment: I was going to say, antik is wrong about that. In the case of A or B then do_something() will execute. With default it will bail.

Comment: @acron, that's the intended behaviour

Comment: Yeah, I know :) Was correcting antik's comment.

Comment: I think this looks far more suspicious & confusing and therefore more harmful than a `goto`.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Perhaps check if the input does get to the `default` branch? Maybe you can provide a more complete example that can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's fine, the `continue` statement relates to the enclosing loop, and your code should be equivalent to (avoiding such jump statements):

```
while (something = get_something()) {
    if (something == A || something == B)
        do_something();
}
```

But if you expect `break` to exit the loop, as your comment suggest (it always tries again with another something, until it evaluates to false), you'll need a different structure.

For example:

```
do {
    something = get_something();
} while (!(something == A || something == B));
do_something();
```

Comment: 'equivalent' only in the semantic sense. the code the compiler generates is very different. with a switch statement, the compiler can generate a jump table which avoids multiple comparisons and thus is much faster than comparing against each element 1 by 1.

Comment: @chacham15, why couldn't the compiler generate the same code for both?

Comment: @avakar switch statements generate jump tables whereas the other representation is a series of logical evaluations. google jump table for more information.

Comment: @chacham15, what prevents the compiler from generating a jump table for the two if statements or a series of logical evaluations for the switch?

Comment: @avakar switch statements require the cases to be constant values, because that is not the case with if statements, it cannot make the same optimization (note: i am speaking in the general case, it is possible given certain requirements (e.g. const values only, only certain logical operators, etc.)  to make the optimization, but it is highly compiler dependent and YMMV).

Answer (score 38):

Yes, continue will be ignored by the switch statement and will go to the condition of the loop to be tested.
I'd like to share this extract from The C Programming Language reference by Ritchie:

> The `continue` statement is related to `break`, but less often used; it causes the next iteration of the enclosing `for`, `while`, or `do` loop to begin. In the `while` and `do`, this means that the test part is executed immediately; in the `for`, control passes to the increment step.
>
> **The continue statement applies only to loops, not to  a `switch` statement. A `continue` inside a `switch` inside a loop causes the next loop iteration.**

I'm not sure about that for C++.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it's OK - it's just like using it in an `if` statement. Of course, you can't use a `break` to break out of  a loop from inside a switch.

Comment: But `if` has no effect on the behaviour of `continue` or `break`. How do you mean it's alike?

Comment: @Matt I mean it will continue the loop in both cases.

Comment: @Neil, okay, confusion averted.

Comment: I think it is still confusing.

Comment: you can use `break` to break out of a loop from inside a switch just like you can break out of an outer loop from inside an inner loop like this : `break 2;` or `break 3;` to go up another level etcetera...

Comment: @KiJéy I can't find any reference for this, and in many years of C programming I have never seen any compiler that supports this... Where on earth did you find this?

Comment: Wow sorry, I saw this in PHP, thought it was an old practice, turns out it's just PHP...

Answer (score 9):

It's syntactically correct and stylistically okay.

Good style requires every `case:` statement should end with one of the following:

```
 break;
 continue;
 return (x);
 exit (x);
 throw (x);
 //fallthrough
```

Additionally, following `case (x):` immediately with

```
 case (y):
 default:
```

is permissible - bundling several cases that have exactly the same effect.

Anything else is suspected to be a mistake, just like `if(a=4){...}`
Of course you need enclosing loop (`while`, `for`, `do...while`) for `continue` to work. It won't loop back to `case()` alone. But a construct like:

```
while(record = getNewRecord())
{
    switch(record.type)
    {
        case RECORD_TYPE_...;
            ...
        break;
        default: //unknown type
            continue; //skip processing this record altogether.
    }
    //...more processing...
}
```

...is okay.

Comment: sorry for necroposting, but I would add that a call to `exit` would also usually be a fine thing to end a switch case with.

Comment: Well, I am going to got all *Dr. Frankenstein* here and also point out that `default:` does not have to be the last/bottom entry - as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3110088/4805858) question points out...

Comment: @SlySven: Lexically, it doesn't, but if you don't have a good reason not to make it last, do make it last. It's often confusing if used at other places.

Comment: @SF. well, I can easily imagine the cases when it would make more sense to make `default:` case the first instead of the last. Like "do this, unless you get the following unusual values, which should be handled as follows".

Answer (score 8):

While technically valid, all these jumps obscure control flow -- especially the `continue` statement.

I would use such a trick as a last resort, not first one.

How about

```
while (something = get_something())
{
    switch (something)
    {
    case A:
    case B:
        do_something();
    }        
}
```

It's shorter and perform its stuff in a more clear way.

Comment: sorry for the confusion Alexander, the code is for demonstration only, i have good reason (i believe) for the actual structure in my code.

Comment: @Matt: That would probably mean an even more obfuscated structure... :)

Answer (score -5):

Switch is not considered as loop so you cannot use **Continue** inside a case statement in switch...

Comment: The `switch` statement is inside a `while` loop, so `continue` is perfectly valid.