# Default switch case in C language

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
  main(){

  int num = 'b';

  switch(num)
  {
      default: printf("Yes\n");
      case 'a': printf("Why!\n"); break;
      case 'A': printf("Bye"); break;

  }
}
```

Why the output of this code is :
Yes
Why!

Why the case 'a' is also executed ?

Comment: because there's no `break` after the `default:` case?

Comment: It's called [fallthrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough).

Comment: break has a meaning in C switches ...

Comment: ask yourself: why is the 'A' case not executed?

Comment: usualy default is the last case; this look like 'special' code...

Comment: shouldn't num be a char?

Comment: Thanks @Cornstalks that's what i want to know.

Comment: @ElDevoper why should `num` be a char? Library functions such as `tolower()` take and return `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane, because the value of num ('b') isn't an integer.

Comment: @ElDevoper yes it is, `'b'` has the integer value 98 which also fits the `char` range..

Comment: using default first or at any place works, it is not how it usualy is documented , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110088/switch-statement-must-default-be-the-last-case is a good question indeed, that's why i +1.

Comment: @WeatherVane it doesn't make sense to write `int num = 'b'` instead of `int num = 98` and after comparing it with an char. Looks like a mistake for me, even if it is valid Code.

Comment: @ElDevoper tell that to the programmers who wrote library functions such a `tolower()` and `strchr()` both of which take `int` parameters for the `char` you think you pass. This loop `for(int i='a'; i<='z'; i++)` is not a mistake which happens to work. It is correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane as I said before, it is valid code. If you wanna go to the limits of an type safe language: Have Fun^^! But if I want to write `int i = 98` I don't even think about `int i = 'b'`. And I'm sure the programmers that have to rewrite my code will be thankfull for that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @ElDevoper for a moment, I thought your link would be about the use of `'b'`. I would have thought `i='b';` was a lot more *KISS* than `i=98;` in the context of referring to the alphabet, as it shows those following exactly what you were doing.

Comment: @WeatherVane I just wanted to give a hint in a comment and ended up in an endless discussion. Your rendition of KISS is more like KI_S. Even the only/first answerer of this question seems to understand what I mean! `char str[] = { 115, 109, 97, 114, 116, 97, 115, 115, 33 };` ;)

Comment: @ElDevoper I would be happier if you spelled it correctly and put `83` as the first character ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code: Will Work Fine

```
int main()
{
      char num = 'b';
      switch(num)
      {          
          case 'a': printf("Why!\n"); break;
          case 'A': printf("Bye"); break;
          default: printf("Yes\n");
      }
  }
```

Put Default Case on End

OR

Put break after Default

Use char instead of int

```
int main()
{
      char num = 'b';
      switch(num)
      {   
         default: printf("Yes\n"); break;
          case 'a': printf("Why!\n"); break;
          case 'A': printf("Bye"); break;

      }
  }
```

Comment: I think the OP is more interested in understanding *why* the behavior occurs than how to "fix" it.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's My Mistake. Thanks for Attantion

Comment: Actually mine - it does work with the `default` first.

Comment: Why do you Randomly write Capital letters on Some of Your words?