# redirect to switch statement from default case

Tags: c, switch-statement

I don't know what is it that I am getting wrong here. Maybe a concept or two.My code proceeds with the rest of the block inside the while loop even when I am trying to redirect my default case to the switch statement when the user inputs any key other than A,S,D or W. The code written is as follows :

```
while(<condition>)
{
    char ch;
    switch(ch=getch())
    {
        case 'W' : case 'w' :
            ..event
            break;
        case 'S' : case 's' :
            ..event
            break;
        case 'A' : case 'a' :
            ..event
            break;
        case 'D' : case 'd' :
            ..event
            break;
        default :
            continue;
    }
   ...actions here with the condition in while using
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior you are getting?

Comment: Move the `...actions here...` into the default case, otherwise it will never execute (the default `continue` skips over it). Meaning it is only hit now if `w,s,a,d` executes when switch avoids the continue.

Comment: Please pick either C or C++.

Comment: Considering just a small variable  in <actions>
count ++;
The counter increments for any other key press as well.

Comment: @FUZxxl why ? This question applies to both languages.

Comment: @chmike Because C and C++ are distinct languages.

Comment: @FUZxxl , but this is applicable to both c and c++ ( except for that `getch()` )

Comment: @NamanNigam It would be helpful if you post a real compilable code in which you are getting this problem.

Comment: It looks like the `continue` applies to the `switch` and not the `while`, as for `break`. What compiler are you using @Naman Nigam ?

Comment: Related [Using continue in a switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146763/using-continue-in-a-switch-statement)

Comment: According to the answer referenced by @Arun A.S, the above code should work as expected. Note that `getch()` is not standard C.

Comment: The continue will for sure cause a jump to "while". The explanation must be somewhere else. Provide the whole code block.

Comment: This comment is not related to your problem, but do not use "char ch" when processing input character by character, use "int ch" instead. This allows to deal with the EOF value as distinct; to call the <ctype.h> macros without problems; etc.

Comment: got it resolved,was missing a break somewhere in a long comment after 'default : '

Comment: @FUZxxl : it was in C++ and the approach is general in both
chmike : compiler independent,i have tried few

Comment: @AntoineL : the use of EOF is not reqd for me,but a point noted for sure.  nielsen : thanx

Comment: @NamanNigam Ah, it's great that you managed to figure out what the problem is on your own. For the next time, please pick either C or C++. These two languages are not the same thing and “applies to both” is almost never the case. Furthermore, there are subtle differences in semantics between C and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments, figured out that the problem was a `break` statement included within the `default` block for switch statement which was the reason for not continuing with the operations.

Answer (score 0):

If an event is handled each time you had a value of (W|S|A|D), then wouldn't you want to put a `continue` before each (W|S|A|D) break?

I think then, doing the above, the `default` would be empty, to keep to your current structure of having actions to do if nothing matches your (W|S|A|D).

Comment: that is not what the requirement is,the (W|S|A|D) are the only console input i want to read and perform actions on for which I am kind of blocking the other keys during console input using the 'continue' in default