# Can anyone explain the interaction of switch, while and continue?

Tags: c, switch-statement, continue

How is the switch statement executed here?
I am especially interested in the use of `continue`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch = 'A';
    while (ch <= 'D')
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
            ch++;
            continue;
        case 'C':
        case 'D':
            ch++;
        }
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
}
```

This outputs `DE`, as you can see [live on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e9596895c263d3d).

Comment: `continue;` corresponds to `while` here

Comment: `break` works on the innermost `for`, `do`, `while` or `switch`. `continue` works only on the innermost `for`, `do` or `while`. This difference can be a gotcha.

Comment: For short and simple programs like this a good start would be to run it in a debugger and follow the execution path. Compiling without optimization could be useful for this.

Comment: What does the code print?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: `Continue` corresponds to the `while` loop in the code.

Initially, value of `ch` is `A` and it matches the first case and since your cases don't have break, once a case is triggered, switch will go through all cases (until break, exit, continue, end of cases etc...). As a result it also enters case `B` and increments the `ch` to `B`. Since it encounters the `continue` it skips the rest of the instructions and begins the next iteration of the `while` loop.

You can run it in [debugger](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/what_is_gdb) to understand these things. You can also use the old-school printfs if needed.

There is also SO thread which discuss in detail about [continue in switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146763/using-continue-in-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Here in char variable ' A' is 65 and 'D' is 68 .If the char value less then or equal in the condition the while loop will run. then in switch condition ch is the value which you defined earlier then the variable value match with the condition of case and increase the value of ch